# Extraction of contents from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to extract only professional Summary from the text..
Could anyone help me to start?

```
Objective:
To be associated with a dynamic organization that gives me ample opportunity to apply my skills to excel in my work field. Always excited to learn and work in new technologies.

Professional Summary:

Having around 3 years of IT experience in various technologies like Java, JSP, Servlets, JDBC, Struts, Hibernate, spring.
Expertise in implementing J2EE technologies (JSP , Servlets , JDBC)
Hands on Experience in Banking and Finance Domain.
Hands on Experience in Struts1 and 2 Framework.
Hands on Experience in Hibernate Framework. 
Hands on Experience in Spring Framework.  
Hands on Experience in J2EE Design Patterns.
Having Java programming skills with JDK 1.6
Having Good knowledge in EJB. 
Having Good Knowledge in OOPS Concept.
Having knowledge of Adobe Live Cycle Tool.

Work Experience:

DurationDesignationOrganizationJune 12 to Feb 13Software EngineerPeocit Technologies, MumbaiJune 10 to June 12Software EngineerSDSoft Solution pvt ltd, Bangalore

Technical Skills:

Operating SystemWindows XP, Windows 7LanguagesJavaApplication/Web ServersJBoss, Apache Tomcat7.J2EE Technologies    JDBC, Servlets, JSP and JSTL.Web ProgrammingCSS, HTML, JQueryRDBMS  MySQL, OracleFramework Struts, Hibernat SpringIDEEclipse,Eclipse.ToolsLog4j, SVN, ANT



Education:

B.Tech (Computer Science) form WBUT in JUNE 2010 with 80%.
```

Comment: take a look at regex https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @Toumash that's not the best approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

If "Work Experience:" always immediately follows the professional summary, you can use the two section headers to partition off the unwanted areas:

```
def get_text_between(s, a, b):
    return s.partition(a)[2].rpartition(b)[0]

with open("input.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

print get_text_between(data, "Professional Summary:", "Work Experience:")
```

Result:

```
Having around 3 years of IT experience in various technologies like Java, JSP, Servlets, JDBC, Struts, Hibernate, spring.
Expertise in implementing J2EE technologies (JSP , Servlets , JDBC)
Hands on Experience in Banking and Finance Domain.
Hands on Experience in Struts1 and 2 Framework.
Hands on Experience in Hibernate Framework.
Hands on Experience in Spring Framework.
Hands on Experience in J2EE Design Patterns.
Having Java programming skills with JDK 1.6
Having Good knowledge in EJB.
Having Good Knowledge in OOPS Concept.
Having knowledge of Adobe Live Cycle Tool.
```

Comment: thanks!! kevin it works , but what if summary is not followed with work experience . is there any logic to extract things with 'titile'